# How can I fix this Android SDK build problem in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-2.2-froyo, facebook

I am using Eclipse for Android dev and everything was going fine until I tried to incorporate the facebook SDK.  Now when I tried to back it out, there appears to be an artifact left behind that Eclipse tries to link the FB library?!?

```
[2010-11-17 18:50:22 - Library Project] Unable to set linked path var '_android_com.facebook.android' for library /Users/mobibob/Projects/workspace/facebook-android-sdk/facebook: Path variable name cannot contain character: ..
```

Any clue where this command / reference is in the build configuration?  I have scoured it as best that I can, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ... as it turns out, it was not so much the Facebook SDK but something that I did in the process of configuring the library reference.  I am not entirely certain of how I  misconfigured, but I was tweaking the various "path" settings such that, once when the automatic build tried to build my project, an import for android.R was added to my source module.  This superseded com.myproject.R and would not resolve the values for resource references.

There were other problems with path order and setting that I modified during the troubleshooting that made it worse.  Recreating the project without Facebook was the first step to discovery and fixing.

Either way, the lesson I learned is that the build error messages can misdirect one to the configuration when the problem is in the source code.